# Kalman filtering in [R] : FKF package and DLM

Tags: r, kalman-filter, state-space-models, dlm

I am trying to implement a time varying state-space model in [R]. Model includes some exogenous variables that are part of the measurement and transition matrices.

I tried multiple packages and my final candidates are to FKF and DLM. However, I have a problem:

In DLM when I try to add seasonality to the model, the code becomes deadly slow. My dataset includes 10 years weekly observations and there is annual seasonality pattern in values. Therefore, I used 
`+ dlmModSeas(51)`
to introduce it. However, I guess it adds 51 dummy variables to the model that makes it tremendously slow. **Question: How to increase the speed of DLM? Do I make a mistake in using seasonality or it is inherently slow?**

I highly appreciate your kind help in advance,

Yours,
Hamid

Comment: Can you make your question explicit? (Eg, I don't see any question marks.) Are you just asking for help with speeding up R code?